# Loop through files in a folder using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to loop through the files of a directory using [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) in Excel 2010.

In the loop, I will need:

- the filename, and
- the date at which the file was formatted.

I have coded the following which works fine if the folder has no more then 50 files, otherwise it is ridiculously slow (I need it to work with folders with >10000 files). The sole problem of this code is that the operation to look up `file.name` takes extremely much time.

*Code that works but is waaaaaay too slow (15 seconds per 100 files):*

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
   Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
   Set MySource = MyObj.GetFolder("c:\testfolder\")
   For Each file In MySource.Files
      If InStr(file.name, "test") > 0 Then
         MsgBox "found"
         Exit Sub
      End If
   Next file
End Sub
```

---

**Problem solved:**

1. My problem has been solved by the solution below using `Dir` in a particular way (20 seconds for 15000 files) and for checking the time stamp using the command `FileDateTime`.
2. Taking into account another answer from below the 20 seconds are reduced to less than 1 second.

Comment: Your initial time seems slow for VBA still. Are you using Application.ScreenUpdating=false?

Comment: You seem to be missing `code` Set MyObj = New FileSystemObject

Comment: I find it rather sad that people are quick to call FSO "slow", but no one mentions the performance penalty you could avoid by simply using early binding instead of late-bound calls against `Object`.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here's my interpretation as a Function Instead:

```
'#######################################################################
'# LoopThroughFiles
'# Function to Loop through files in current directory and return filenames
'# Usage: LoopThroughFiles ActiveWorkbook.Path, "txt" 'inputDirectoryToScanForFile
'# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba
'#######################################################################
Function LoopThroughFiles(inputDirectoryToScanForFile, filenameCriteria) As String

    Dim StrFile As String
    'Debug.Print "in LoopThroughFiles. inputDirectoryToScanForFile: ", inputDirectoryToScanForFile

    StrFile = Dir(inputDirectoryToScanForFile & "\*" & filenameCriteria)
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Debug.Print StrFile
        StrFile = Dir

    Loop

End Function
```

Comment: why function, when nothing is returned back ? isn't this same as the answer given by brettdj, except it is enclosed in a function

Answer (score 299):

`Dir` takes wild cards so you could make a big difference adding the filter for `test` up front and avoiding testing each file

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim StrFile As String
    StrFile = Dir("c:\testfolder\*test*")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Debug.Print StrFile
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: GREAT. This just improved the runtime from 20 seconds to <1 seconds. That's a big improvement, since the code will be run pretty often. THANK YOU!!

Comment: It could be because the Do while...loop is better then while... wend. more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728334/do-while-loop-and-while-wend-loop-whats-the-difference

Comment: I don't think by that improvement level (20 - xxx times) - I think its the wildcard making a difference.

Comment: DIR()  does not seem to return Hidden files.

Comment: @hamish, you can change its argument to return different type of files (hidden, system, etc.) - see MS documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function

Comment: I don't understand the line `StrFile = Dir`. This doesn't work for me. I used `Output = StrFile` instead.

Comment: For those coming across the comment of Kar.ma and are wondering the same thing, `StrFile = Dir` in the While loop is simply setting StrFile to the next found file in the previously set up `Dir("c:\testfolder\*test*"`. As an example: if there was a test1.xlsx and a test2.xlsx, the `Debug.Print StrFile` would first give the test1 and then `StrFile = Dir` would find the next match which is the test2 (and so stay in the while loop). Hope that clears things up a bit.

Answer (score 168):

Dir seems to be very fast.

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
   file = Dir("c:\testfolder\")
   While (file <> "")
      If InStr(file, "test") > 0 Then
         MsgBox "found " & file
         Exit Sub
      End If
     file = Dir
  Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much. I do use Dir but I didn't know that you can use it that way also. In addition with the command `FileDateTime` my problem is solved.

Comment: Still one question. I could severely improve the speed if DIR would loop starting with the most recent files. Do you see any way to do this?

Comment: My latter question has been settled by the comment below from brettdj.

Comment: Dir will `not` however `traverse the whole directory tree`. In case needed: http://analystcave.com/vba-dir-function-how-to-traverse-directories/#Traversing_directories

Comment: Dir will also be interrupted by other Dir commands, so if you run a subroutine containing Dir, it can "reset" it in your original sub.  Using FSO as per original question eliminates this issue.

EDIT: just seen the post by @LimaNightHawk below, same thing

Comment: So `dir(path)` takes the first file of `path` and then you have to call dir without arg again to get the rest of the path as stated [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dir-function-1a1a4275-f92f-4ae4-8b87-41e4513bba2e?ocmsassetid=ha001228824&correlationid=93c68ac7-3a86-49d1-a45b-867a7a4ea782&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us): `Dir returns the first file name that matches pathname. To get any additional file names..`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24018460/1705829) answer here.

Answer (score 30):

The Dir function is the way to go, but **the problem is that you cannot use the `Dir` function recursively**, as stated [here, towards the bottom](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dir-function-HA001228824.aspx).

The way that I've handled this is to use the `Dir` function to get all of the sub-folders for the target folder and load them into an array, then pass the array into a function that recurses.

Here's a class that I wrote that accomplishes this, it includes the ability to search for filters. (*You'll have to forgive the Hungarian Notation, this was written when it was all the rage.*)

```
Private m_asFilters() As String
Private m_asFiles As Variant
Private m_lNext As Long
Private m_lMax As Long

Public Function GetFileList(ByVal ParentDir As String, Optional ByVal sSearch As String, Optional ByVal Deep As Boolean = True) As Variant
    m_lNext = 0
    m_lMax = 0

    ReDim m_asFiles(0)
    If Len(sSearch) Then
        m_asFilters() = Split(sSearch, "|")
    Else
        ReDim m_asFilters(0)
    End If

    If Deep Then
        Call RecursiveAddFiles(ParentDir)
    Else
        Call AddFiles(ParentDir)
    End If

    If m_lNext Then
        ReDim Preserve m_asFiles(m_lNext - 1)
        GetFileList = m_asFiles
    End If

End Function

Private Sub RecursiveAddFiles(ByVal ParentDir As String)
    Dim asDirs() As String
    Dim l As Long
    On Error GoTo ErrRecursiveAddFiles
    'Add the files in 'this' directory!


    Call AddFiles(ParentDir)

    ReDim asDirs(-1 To -1)
    asDirs = GetDirList(ParentDir)
    For l = 0 To UBound(asDirs)
        Call RecursiveAddFiles(asDirs(l))
    Next l
    On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
ErrRecursiveAddFiles:
End Sub
Private Function GetDirList(ByVal ParentDir As String) As String()
    Dim sDir As String
    Dim asRet() As String
    Dim l As Long
    Dim lMax As Long

    If Right(ParentDir, 1) <> "\" Then
        ParentDir = ParentDir & "\"
    End If
    sDir = Dir(ParentDir, vbDirectory Or vbHidden Or vbSystem)
    Do While Len(sDir)
        If GetAttr(ParentDir & sDir) And vbDirectory Then
            If Not (sDir = "." Or sDir = "..") Then
                If l >= lMax Then
                    lMax = lMax + 10
                    ReDim Preserve asRet(lMax)
                End If
                asRet(l) = ParentDir & sDir
                l = l + 1
            End If
        End If
        sDir = Dir
    Loop
    If l Then
        ReDim Preserve asRet(l - 1)
        GetDirList = asRet()
    End If
End Function
Private Sub AddFiles(ByVal ParentDir As String)
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim l As Long

    If Right(ParentDir, 1) <> "\" Then
        ParentDir = ParentDir & "\"
    End If

    For l = 0 To UBound(m_asFilters)
        sFile = Dir(ParentDir & "\" & m_asFilters(l), vbArchive Or vbHidden Or vbNormal Or vbReadOnly Or vbSystem)
        Do While Len(sFile)
            If Not (sFile = "." Or sFile = "..") Then
                If m_lNext >= m_lMax Then
                    m_lMax = m_lMax + 100
                    ReDim Preserve m_asFiles(m_lMax)
                End If
                m_asFiles(m_lNext) = ParentDir & sFile
                m_lNext = m_lNext + 1
            End If
            sFile = Dir
        Loop
    Next l
End Sub
```

Comment: If i would like to list files found in column, what could be an implementation of this?

Comment: @jechaviz The GetFileList method returns an array of String. You would probably just iterate over the array and add the items to a ListView, or something like that. Details on how to show items in a listview are probably beyond the scope of this post.

Comment: Many Thanks, just to suggest that at the end of `GetFileList` Function, an Else could be added: `If m_lNext Then` ...`Else` ... `ReDim GetFileList(0) As String`. As suggested here:  [https://stackoverflow.com/a/35221544/6406135]

Answer (score 6):

`Dir` function loses focus easily when I handle and process files from other folders.

I've gotten better results with the component `FileSystemObject`.

Full example is given here:

http://www.xl-central.com/list-files-fso.html

Don't forget to set a reference in the Visual Basic Editor to *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* (by using Tools > References)

Give it a try!

Comment: Technically this is the method that the asker is using, they just don't have their references included which would be slowing this method down.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that returns a collection that you can then iterate through  - you could use a dictionary if you wanted more than just file name

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = LoopThroughFiles(ThisWorkbook.Path, ".xlsx")
    For Each f In c
        Debug.Print f
    Next
End Sub

Function LoopThroughFiles(inputDirectoryToScanForFile, filenameCriteria) As Collection
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim StrFile As String
    'Debug.Print "in LoopThroughFiles. inputDirectoryToScanForFile: ", inputDirectoryToScanForFile
    StrFile = Dir(inputDirectoryToScanForFile & "\*" & filenameCriteria)
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        '//Debug.Print StrFile
        col.Add StrFile
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
    Set LoopThroughFiles = col
End Function
```

Comment: Assuming a user of this code would be using `Option Explicit` then you need to declare `f` ie `Dim f As Variant` otherwise the code will not run

Answer (score -2):

Try this one. ([LINK](http://snippetcoders.com/Snippet/all-excel-sheets-are-saved-as-separated-excel-workbooks-same-folder-as-current-file/))

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim FolderName As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook
DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
FolderName = xWb.Path & "\" & xWb.Name & " " & DateString
MkDir FolderName
For Each xWs In xWb.Worksheets
    xWs.Copy
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        Select Case xWb.FileFormat
            Case 51:
                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If Application.ActiveWorkbook.HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56:
                FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else:
                FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
        End Select
    End If
    xFile = FolderName & "\" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & FileExtStr
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```